# Node.js: methodOverride doesn't work

Tags: node.js, methods, put

In the server side:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.listen(8000);

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
});

app.put('/update', function (req, res) {
  res.send("update!");
})
```

I want test the `put` method

in the client side:

```
<form action="/update">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

but the result is

```
Cannot GET /update?_method=put
```

so, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the `bodyParser` middleware too:

```
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `/upadte` should be `/update`.

edit: try using `method="post"` in your form tag.

Comment: I have correct the `update`, but it still don't work, as description above

Comment: post wasn't necessary, check robertklep's answer.